# Who put the sled in the mountains at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-giver

In the movie [The Giver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435651/), giver/Jeff Bridges showed Jonas a sled as past memory. He showed receiver a house, he gave him a feeling about riding a sled.

At the end when Jonas went to cross the boundary of memory, found a sled and after crossing the boundary saw a house exactly same as the memory. Now who put the sled there? Did the giver kept it there for any receiver to help him/her for crossing the boundary? Did the giver been there before? Or just coincidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's likely that any member of the Community left the sled there.  Unfortunately, there's no evidence within the film to suggest who might have left it or why.

For a clue as to what's happening, and why that scene seems to not fit, I'll have to share a semi-spoiler from the end of the book:

> In the book, it's intentionally left unclear as to whether Jonas
>  actually found a sled, or if he imagined it in a delirium as he froze
>  to death.

---

> While I personally believe that he died, the ending is described
>  vaguely enough that it's also possible that he just stumbled across a
>  village of free people, and found a sled that one of their children
>  had left unattended.  In the book, he only slides down a hill, not a
>  mountain, and he winds up someplace populated: he sees lights from
>  windows, and hears singing and music.

The movie throws that ambiguity out the window by showing him passing through the barrier on the sled, then showing emotion returning to the people of the Community.

The book didn't have any scenes outside of Jonas' point of view; so, when the filmmakers tried to mimic the end of the book, they unfortunately rendered it incomprehensible by showing us what was happening in the community at the time.